# What the guiding guide guide

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Here's a riddle I created for Puzzling:

> Two guardians for a guide
> Radiant ladies on her side.
> **Oh back**, the first preside;
> **Herb pac** the second replied.
> Both have notorious great pride,
> For **id luny** was cast aside.
> Read the lines and please don't hide
> What the guiding guide guide.

**HINT #1:**

> The question is what is guided by the guide.

**HINT #2:**

> Take a close look at the **DOLB** words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It think you are referring to:

> The North Star, Polaris

Two guardians for a guide

> Polaris was a guide for sailors in the past to locate the direction they were going

Radiant ladies on her side.

> In the Ursa Minor Constellation, Polaris has two bright stars on its side, Kochab and Pherkad. These two are the brightest stars in the constellation apart from Polaris.

Oh back, the first preside;
Herb pac the second replied

> Oh back is an anagram for Kochab and Herb pac where b is reversed to make d and c to k because they sound alike is an anagram for Kochab.

Both have notorious great pride.

> This is because they are brighter than the other stars of the constellation and the nightsky so they would feel superior.

For id luny was cast aside.

> Id luny is an anagram for Yildun and it is cast aside because it is located in the Handle of the constellation, far away from Kochab and Pherkad.

Comment: That was great! You totally got it!